# Does this query use index for group by stage in Psql?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, aggregation-framework, explain

My table in Postgresql consist of 1.2m rows.I am using combound index on timestamp1,id13
My query look like this:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE ,VERBOSE, COSTS,BUFFERS ) select date_trunc('day',timestamp1) as day,avg(id9) from oneindextwocolumns where timestamp1>='2019-01-01 00:00:00' and timestamp1<='2020-12-31 00:55:00'  group by day,id13 order by day desc
```

The explain plan is this:

```
"GroupAggregate  (cost=40802.98..46082.38 rows=211176 width=24) (actual time=150.115..213.289 rows=91645 loops=1)"
"  Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timestamp1)), avg(id9), id13"
"  Group Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, oneindextwocolumns.timestamp1)), oneindextwocolumns.id13"
"  Buffers: shared hit=5937, temp read=875 written=877"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=40802.98..41330.92 rows=211176 width=24) (actual time=150.088..169.306 rows=210252 loops=1)"
"        Output: (date_trunc('day'::text, timestamp1)), id13, id9"
"        Sort Key: (date_trunc('day'::text, oneindextwocolumns.timestamp1)) DESC, oneindextwocolumns.id13"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7000kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=5937, temp read=875 written=877"
"        ->  Index Scan using oneindextwocolumns_timestamp1_id13_idx on public.oneindextwocolumns  (cost=0.43..22126.48 rows=211176 width=24) (actual time=0.020..67.899 rows=210252 loops=1)"
"              Output: date_trunc('day'::text, timestamp1), id13, id9"
"              Index Cond: ((oneindextwocolumns.timestamp1 >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (oneindextwocolumns.timestamp1 <= '2020-12-31 00:55:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=5937"
"Planning Time: 0.118 ms"
"Execution Time: 217.945 ms"
```

How can i know if the group stage uses index?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ? " Index Scan using oneindextwocolumns_timestamp1_id13_idx ". But you do not share info on how this index `oneindextwocolumns_timestamp1_id13_idx` was created

Comment: @Luuk I am using combound index on timestamp1,id13

Comment: @Luuk Is there a way in general to find out in the explain plan if a query use index group by?

Comment: @Luuk I did read that article a while ago but i didnt understand when a group by use index..anyway thanks!

Comment: There is also a nice explanation on multicolumn indexes here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-multicolumn-indexes/   It does not cover `group by`, but if you create an example, with enough records, and play a bit with it, you should find out how to do it pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

It does not use the index to provide the order.  If it did, what would the function of the sort occurring before the aggregate be?  If it used the order supplied by the index to do the grouping, then the plan would show a GroupAgg being fed directly by the IndexScan with no Sort in between.

There is a caveat to that.  In the newest versions of PostgreSQL, there is also an Incremental Sort. In this, the index (or something) supplies rows in a certain order which is mostly what we need, but then we need to re-sort the ties to put them in a specific order.  This can be used for example if the index provides ordering by `(col1)`, but we need ordering by `(col1,col2)`.  But that is not the case here--your sitution is not eligible for such sort, and if one were being used the sort node would be labeled as "Incremental Sort", not just as "Sort".

The planner does not think through the fact that ordering by timestamp1 will necessarily order by `date_trunc('day'::text, timestamp1)` as well.  That is a missing optimization.  Maybe someone will implement it some day.

Comment: I didnt understood.Can you say it more specificaly please?What do you mean here ``` If it did, what would the function of the sort occurring before the aggregate be?```

Comment: If it did use the index for grouping shouldnt the explain plan before the sort stage would be something index scan?

Comment: If the sort stage use and index then the group also use an index?

Comment: Sort, other than Incremental Sort, does not use an Index.  If a sort is not needed because the data is already in order, then no Sort node would be present.

Comment: And what about group by?How can i know in general if a group by use the index from the explain plan?

Comment: As far as I know, the only way for a GROUP BY to be done "using an index" would be a "GroupAgg" or a "Group" with either no Sort feeding it, or with an Incremental Sort feeding it.  But that would be version specific, maybe a future version will implement grouping via skip scans or something.